# Possible to have the same Search Navigation across all sites in a site collection in SP2013?

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search

Just like using scopes in SharePoint 2010, is it possible to assign the same Search Navigation options to all sites in a site collection, so they share the same verticals?

Comment: With search navigation you mean the refiners on the left side of the search result page?

Comment: No, this is in regards to what SharePoint 2010 called "scopes". From an end user perspective, being able to select the 'scope', or now "Search Navigation", at the same time as entering the search query. Does this help?